# How to call functions by name in javascript where entire code is enclosed within some anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I want to write function that takes a function name as an argument and calls it. Normally i could do this using window[funcname]. However all my code is enclosed within an anonymous function and hence the namespace of the function is now window. In this case how could i write this function.

Comment: could you show us some code please?

Comment: see my answer here.
[call by name in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46090820/7771019)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign your functions to properties of an object:

```
var myFuncs = {
    func1: function() {
        //Do something
    },
    func2: function() {
        //Do something else
    }
};
```

You can then call `func1` just like you suggest, but replacing `window` with `myFuncs`, like so:

```
myFuncs["func1"]();
```

Answer (score 1):

Store your functions in an object as properties and retrieve them by name.